# Saving Release pipeline in yaml

Tags: azure-devops

Just like build pipelines I Want to save release pipeline in yaml and version control it in git, diff, merge, revert

it is possible to download release pipeline in yaml format

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Azure DevOps, YAML release pipelines?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52323065/azure-devops-yaml-release-pipelines)

Comment: @forvaidya Not get your latest information, if you have any concern, feel free to share it here.

Answer (score 1):

To enable YAML Release Pipeline, you need to enable **Multi-stage YAML pipelines** in Preview features:

[image]

Check [Multi-stage YAML pipelines](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/whats-new-with-azure-pipelines/) for more information.

Here are some documents and cases you can refer to :

- [YAML schema reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema%2Cparameter-schema)
- [Converting Classic Azure DevOps Pipelines to YAML](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/converting-classic-azure-devops-pipelines-to-yaml/)
- [Using Azure DevOps, how do I migrate a release pipeline to code,
  similar to build pipeline yml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57879527/using-azure-devops-how-do-i-migrate-a-release-pipeline-to-code-similar-to-buil)