# Your build pipeline references an undefined variable named 'Parameters.WebsiteName'

Tags: azure-devops

I have a working release pipeline that I set up years ago.

However when I view the YAML I see

```
#Your build pipeline references an undefined variable named ‘Parameters.WebsiteName’. 
Create or edit the build pipeline for this YAML file, define the variable on the 
Variables tab. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=865972

steps:
- task: IISWebAppDeploymentOnMachineGroup@0
  displayName: 'IIS Web App Deploy'
  inputs:
    WebSiteName: '$(Parameters.WebsiteName)'
    VirtualApplication: betaapiforme
    Package: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/_myapp/drop/ApiForMe.WebApi.zip'
    TakeAppOfflineFlag: True
    JSONFiles: |
     **/appsettings.json
```

I can see the website name in the UI for the pipeline.
It is not editable.
[image: website name]

Why is the YAML showing a warning?

Comment: The YAML is showing you a warning for exactly the reason it says. You're using a feature of classic pipelines (linked parameters) that doesn't exist in YAML. Thus, it can't translate the parameter into YAML and shows you a warning.

Comment: Thank you. I see this is relevant https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57879527/using-azure-devops-how-do-i-migrate-a-release-pipeline-to-code-similar-to-buil